# reading values from database of Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I wanna read database which is already created by my Android application but in some other activity. Like one activity is creating database and other is reading it. But when i started reading thought other activity like this:

```
List<String> names = this.dh.selectJname();
```

then this showed "Null pointer Exception".

Comment: can you please post the logcat output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you made sure to initialize your dh variable?